# How to bring font-awesome icon to the front?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an icon I want to bring to the front of the page but I cant seem to get it to work.

I've tried using z-index and setting 1 on the background image and 100 on the icon.

CSS

```
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1080px;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
fa-chevron-right {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top:500px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div id=content>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2]">
      <div id=slider [@flyInOut]="flyInOut" *ngIf="i == gameIndex " [ngStyle]="{'background-image':game}">

      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <span class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-5x" data-toggle="modal" role="button" aria-hidden="true"
      (click)="movePictureRight()"></span>
    <app-game-gallery></app-game-gallery>
  </div>
```

Comment: A screenshot would help a lot. Possibly one with the current scenario and one with the expected result.

Comment: You are missing a dot (.) in your CSS in front of fa-chevron-right

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that